# Running docker flyway migration doesnt find my column. Cannot delete

Tags: docker, psql, flyway

So get the following error message when running docker with flyway migration:

> migrate_1  | Message    : ERROR: column "my_column" of relation
>   "my_table" does not exist migrate_1  | Location   :
>   /flyway/sql/V1_10__tables.sql (/flyway/sql/V1_10__tables.sql)

When I log in to psql and `SELECT * FROM my_table;`

> It shows my_column | my_column2 | my_column3 
>   -----------+------+------------+---------+-----+------+--------+--------------+--------------+-------

It doesn't have any constraints either. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you able to share the migration file?

Comment: I was only trying to DELETE my_column. I solved the problem by dropping the whole table and recreating it. Tough I would like to know what caused this error. My only assumption is that I did some INSERTs by logging in to the db from terminal. Propably shoulnd't do that with a docker flyway migrated db.